# Reclassify polygon shapefile into different classes based on features

Tags: arcmap, shapefile, polygon, reclassify

I'm using ArcMap 10.4
I have small problems with my map.
I have 7 years of data and I want to classify my map for the different years in different classes.
In other words, the year 2010 have different classes for all features. Up to the 2016 year
In total 7 maps with different classes

I need to have seven different map with each year related fields as classeses

Answer (score 0):

You can create data frames with using the same layer and classify each year in different data frames.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have several data frames, but how I make each frame different classes based on the fields?

Comment: Drag drop your layer to other data frames. The feature layer will be copied in your mxd project file not your database but you can classify your each layer with different classes. You should use layout view if you want to see them together.